# How to render a react component on any other page other than index.html

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I created a basic react app with

```
npx create-react-app
```

I can create components in the `index.js` and I'm able to render them to an element in the `index.html`.

However that's the only page I can render them too, I can't for example use the same component on the `login.html` page or any other page other than `index.html`

I'm testing this with `npm start`.

Comment: You would only have a single html file and then create multiple component, and render the top level component in the html file. for multiple pages in your App, you would make use of a router typically react-router

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Is there no other way? To make it work with multiple pages?

Comment: You can have any number of HTML page. But you would need a different setup for each. And load a specific javascript file for each. Then make your links as direct links from page to page. Dont expect Redux to work between page however (without re-fetching data)

Comment: The best solution seems to be to just use pure js on the other pages.

Answer (score 3):

Commonly React is used for single page applications, so you just render the app in a single page, then use routing (with `react-router` commonly) for simulate browser navigation.

However you *can* render it on multiple pages... you only need to copy your activation JavaScript on other pages

Just copy this on your `login.html` (taken from default create-react-app output):

```html
<noscript>
  You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would you need this? Remember that React, for his own nature, claims to be a SPA (**Single Page Application**). This should be enough to let you understand that the single page is (*should be*) index.html.

Anyway, you can do it by looking at the default index.html file created by create-react-app and also at the manifest.json file.

Starting by the manifest.json, you should have this JSON:

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Or something like this. You can se a "start_url" property, which is the starting point that create-react-app webpack dev-server will, by default, serve to you when you request ANY path at the local address you are running it (localhost:3000 normally). By changing this property, you can make it serve the page you want, e.g. login.html.

Now, looking at index.html default code you should have something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, at the end of the page there is a

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

Which is exactly where React renders what ReactDOM.render(jsx, ElementID) jsx is. In fact, if you look in index.js, ReactDOM is like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Something />,
, document.getElementByID('root'));
```

You can see that ElementID ('root') is the id of the div element where you want to render the jsx (). If you create a new page, say login.html, copy-paste the index.html content and change the  element ID, you can then choose to render your content there changing also the referral ElementID of ReactDOM.render().
Working on this you should get the result you want to, but as said before, in my opinion you shouldn't need this.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, ReactJS (with the create-react) seems to be always looking at index.html, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

To use files other than `index.html`, you need to do changes at four positions in 2 files.

The files are `project_directory\public\manifest.json` and `project_directory\node_modules\react-scripts\config\paths.js`

1. At `project_directory\public\manifest.json`

- **Before Change**

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

- **After Change**

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./yourNewHtmlFile.html",  // change only this line
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

2. At `project_directory\node_modules\react-scripts\config\paths.js`

- **Before Change**

  ```
    // @remove-on-eject-begin
    /**
     * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
     *
     * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
     * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
     */
    // @remove-on-eject-end
    'use strict';

    const path = require('path');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const getPublicUrlOrPath = require('react-dev-utils/getPublicUrlOrPath');

    // Make sure any symlinks in the project folder are resolved:
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/637
    const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
    const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

    // We use `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable or "homepage" field to infer
    // "public path" at which the app is served.
    // webpack needs to know it to put the right <script> hrefs into HTML even in
    // single-page apps that may serve index.html for nested URLs like /todos/42.
    // We can't use a relative path in HTML because we don't want to load something
    // like /todos/42/static/js/bundle.7289d.js. We have to know the root.
    const publicUrlOrPath = getPublicUrlOrPath(
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    require(resolveApp('package.json')).homepage,
    process.env.PUBLIC_URL
    );

    const buildPath = process.env.BUILD_PATH || 'build';

    const moduleFileExtensions = [
    'web.mjs',
    'mjs',
    'web.js',
    'js',
    'web.ts',
    'ts',
    'web.tsx',
    'tsx',
    'json',
    'web.jsx',
    'jsx',
    ];

    // Resolve file paths in the same order as webpack
    const resolveModule = (resolveFn, filePath) => {
    const extension = moduleFileExtensions.find(extension =>
      fs.existsSync(resolveFn(`${filePath}.${extension}`))
    );

    if (extension) {
      return resolveFn(`${filePath}.${extension}`);
    }

    return resolveFn(`${filePath}.js`);
    };

    // config after eject: we're in ./config/
    module.exports = {
    dotenv: resolveApp('.env'),
    appPath: resolveApp('.'),
    appBuild: resolveApp(buildPath),
    appPublic: resolveApp('public'),
    appHtml: resolveApp('public/index.html'), 
    appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/index'),
    appPackageJson: resolveApp('package.json'),
    appSrc: resolveApp('src'),
    appTsConfig: resolveApp('tsconfig.json'),
    appJsConfig: resolveApp('jsconfig.json'),
    yarnLockFile: resolveApp('yarn.lock'),
    testsSetup: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/setupTests'),
    proxySetup: resolveApp('src/setupProxy.js'),
    appNodeModules: resolveApp('node_modules'),
    swSrc: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/service-worker'),
    publicUrlOrPath,
    };

    // @remove-on-eject-begin
    const resolveOwn = relativePath => path.resolve(__dirname, '..', relativePath);

    // config before eject: we're in ./node_modules/react-scripts/config/
    module.exports = {
    dotenv: resolveApp('.env'),
    appPath: resolveApp('.'),
    appBuild: resolveApp(buildPath),
    appPublic: resolveApp('public'),
    appHtml: resolveApp('public/index.html'),
    appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/index'),
    appPackageJson: resolveApp('package.json'),
    appSrc: resolveApp('src'),
    appTsConfig: resolveApp('tsconfig.json'),
    appJsConfig: resolveApp('jsconfig.json'),
    yarnLockFile: resolveApp('yarn.lock'),
    testsSetup: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/setupTests'),
    proxySetup: resolveApp('src/setupProxy.js'),
    appNodeModules: resolveApp('node_modules'),
    swSrc: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/service-worker'),
    publicUrlOrPath,
    // These properties only exist before ejecting:
    ownPath: resolveOwn('.'),
    ownNodeModules: resolveOwn('node_modules'), // This is empty on npm 3
    appTypeDeclarations: resolveApp('src/react-app-env.d.ts'),
    ownTypeDeclarations: resolveOwn('lib/react-app.d.ts'),
    };

    const ownPackageJson = require('../package.json');
    const reactScriptsPath = resolveApp(`node_modules/${ownPackageJson.name}`);
    const reactScriptsLinked =
    fs.existsSync(reactScriptsPath) &&
    fs.lstatSync(reactScriptsPath).isSymbolicLink();

    // config before publish: we're in ./packages/react-scripts/config/
    if (
    !reactScriptsLinked &&
    __dirname.indexOf(path.join('packages', 'react-scripts', 'config')) !== -1
    ) {
    const templatePath = '../cra-template/template';
    module.exports = {
      dotenv: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/.env`),
      appPath: resolveApp('.'),
      appBuild: resolveOwn(path.join('../..', buildPath)),
      appPublic: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/public`),
      appHtml: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/public/index.html`),
      appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveOwn, `${templatePath}/src/index`),
      appPackageJson: resolveOwn('package.json'),
      appSrc: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/src`),
      appTsConfig: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/tsconfig.json`),
      appJsConfig: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/jsconfig.json`),
      yarnLockFile: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/yarn.lock`),
      testsSetup: resolveModule(resolveOwn, `${templatePath}/src/setupTests`),
      proxySetup: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/src/setupProxy.js`),
      appNodeModules: resolveOwn('node_modules'),
      swSrc: resolveModule(resolveOwn, `${templatePath}/src/service-worker`),
      publicUrlOrPath,
      // These properties only exist before ejecting:
      ownPath: resolveOwn('.'),
      ownNodeModules: resolveOwn('node_modules'),
      appTypeDeclarations: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/src/react-app-env.d.ts`),
      ownTypeDeclarations: resolveOwn('lib/react-app.d.ts'),
    };
    }
    // @remove-on-eject-end

    module.exports.moduleFileExtensions = moduleFileExtensions;
  ```
- **After Change**

  ```
    // @remove-on-eject-begin
    /**
     * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
     *
     * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
     * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
     */
    // @remove-on-eject-end
    'use strict';

    const path = require('path');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const getPublicUrlOrPath = require('react-dev-utils/getPublicUrlOrPath');

    // Make sure any symlinks in the project folder are resolved:
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/637
    const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
    const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

    // We use `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable or "homepage" field to infer
    // "public path" at which the app is served.
    // webpack needs to know it to put the right <script> hrefs into HTML even in
    // single-page apps that may serve index.html for nested URLs like /todos/42.
    // We can't use a relative path in HTML because we don't want to load something
    // like /todos/42/static/js/bundle.7289d.js. We have to know the root.
    const publicUrlOrPath = getPublicUrlOrPath(
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    require(resolveApp('package.json')).homepage,
    process.env.PUBLIC_URL
    );

    const buildPath = process.env.BUILD_PATH || 'build';

    const moduleFileExtensions = [
    'web.mjs',
    'mjs',
    'web.js',
    'js',
    'web.ts',
    'ts',
    'web.tsx',
    'tsx',
    'json',
    'web.jsx',
    'jsx',
    ];

    // Resolve file paths in the same order as webpack
    const resolveModule = (resolveFn, filePath) => {
    const extension = moduleFileExtensions.find(extension =>
      fs.existsSync(resolveFn(`${filePath}.${extension}`))
    );

    if (extension) {
      return resolveFn(`${filePath}.${extension}`);
    }

    return resolveFn(`${filePath}.js`);
    };

    // config after eject: we're in ./config/
    module.exports = {
    dotenv: resolveApp('.env'),
    appPath: resolveApp('.'),
    appBuild: resolveApp(buildPath),
    appPublic: resolveApp('public'),
    appHtml: resolveApp('public/yourNewHtmlFile.html'),  // change this line
    appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/index'),
    appPackageJson: resolveApp('package.json'),
    appSrc: resolveApp('src'),
    appTsConfig: resolveApp('tsconfig.json'),
    appJsConfig: resolveApp('jsconfig.json'),
    yarnLockFile: resolveApp('yarn.lock'),
    testsSetup: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/setupTests'),
    proxySetup: resolveApp('src/setupProxy.js'),
    appNodeModules: resolveApp('node_modules'),
    swSrc: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/service-worker'),
    publicUrlOrPath,
    };

    // @remove-on-eject-begin
    const resolveOwn = relativePath => path.resolve(__dirname, '..', relativePath);

    // config before eject: we're in ./node_modules/react-scripts/config/
    module.exports = {
    dotenv: resolveApp('.env'),
    appPath: resolveApp('.'),
    appBuild: resolveApp(buildPath),
    appPublic: resolveApp('public'),
    appHtml: resolveApp('public/yourNewHtmlFile.html'),  // change this line
    appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/index'),
    appPackageJson: resolveApp('package.json'),
    appSrc: resolveApp('src'),
    appTsConfig: resolveApp('tsconfig.json'),
    appJsConfig: resolveApp('jsconfig.json'),
    yarnLockFile: resolveApp('yarn.lock'),
    testsSetup: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/setupTests'),
    proxySetup: resolveApp('src/setupProxy.js'),
    appNodeModules: resolveApp('node_modules'),
    swSrc: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/service-worker'),
    publicUrlOrPath,
    // These properties only exist before ejecting:
    ownPath: resolveOwn('.'),
    ownNodeModules: resolveOwn('node_modules'), // This is empty on npm 3
    appTypeDeclarations: resolveApp('src/react-app-env.d.ts'),
    ownTypeDeclarations: resolveOwn('lib/react-app.d.ts'),
    };

    const ownPackageJson = require('../package.json');
    const reactScriptsPath = resolveApp(`node_modules/${ownPackageJson.name}`);
    const reactScriptsLinked =
    fs.existsSync(reactScriptsPath) &&
    fs.lstatSync(reactScriptsPath).isSymbolicLink();

    // config before publish: we're in ./packages/react-scripts/config/
    if (
    !reactScriptsLinked &&
    __dirname.indexOf(path.join('packages', 'react-scripts', 'config')) !== -1
    ) {
    const templatePath = '../cra-template/template';
    module.exports = {
      dotenv: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/.env`),
      appPath: resolveApp('.'),
      appBuild: resolveOwn(path.join('../..', buildPath)),
      appPublic: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/public`),
      appHtml: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/public/yourNewHtmlFile.html`),  // change this line
      appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveOwn, `${templatePath}/src/index`),
      appPackageJson: resolveOwn('package.json'),
      appSrc: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/src`),
      appTsConfig: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/tsconfig.json`),
      appJsConfig: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/jsconfig.json`),
      yarnLockFile: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/yarn.lock`),
      testsSetup: resolveModule(resolveOwn, `${templatePath}/src/setupTests`),
      proxySetup: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/src/setupProxy.js`),
      appNodeModules: resolveOwn('node_modules'),
      swSrc: resolveModule(resolveOwn, `${templatePath}/src/service-worker`),
      publicUrlOrPath,
      // These properties only exist before ejecting:
      ownPath: resolveOwn('.'),
      ownNodeModules: resolveOwn('node_modules'),
      appTypeDeclarations: resolveOwn(`${templatePath}/src/react-app-env.d.ts`),
      ownTypeDeclarations: resolveOwn('lib/react-app.d.ts'),
    };
    }
    // @remove-on-eject-end

    module.exports.moduleFileExtensions = moduleFileExtensions;
  ```

**And that's it**