# How can I use React-route correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This situation: I have the main page index.html. I don't use React on it. But on the main page there is a link on the game page where I use React.

I need create application on the game page, but webpack(I think) can render app only on the `index.html.` I have container for render on the game page. But react ignores it. On the other side when I creating container for rander on the main page all is okey.

Peace of code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import ElectronApp from './components/ElectronApp';

import {
  HashRouter,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom'


ReactDOM.render(
  <HashRouter>
    <Route path="/electron-game.html" component={ElectronApp} />
  </HashRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

What can I do to fix my problem, I don't shure that I need use Router.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render a react component on any other page other than index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50234042/how-to-render-a-react-component-on-any-other-page-other-than-index-html)

Answer (score 0):

I know you say you don't need React in the main page, but it may be easier (if you really want to use react router like this), to handle the link as a react component, and then have it route to the Electron App.

See here for a relatively clear example of using React Router:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

I would suggest taking a look at how things are working on that page.

Also, one thing I noticed in your example -- you don't need the 'html' in '/electron-game.html'.  It's not getting an actual html resource.