# How do I handle multiple routes in flask that should return static files from react build?

Tags: reactjs, flask

**Overview**

I'm working on a project with a flask backend and a react frontend. I run the application with:

```sh
python3 main.py
```

In `main.py` I have the following that specifies to serve `index.html` when the user requests `'/'`:

```py
# main.py
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="build", static_url_path="/")


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")
```

Works like a dream. Now I'm adding more routes in the react app:

```js
# App.js
import React from 'react';

import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import SomePage from './SomePage';
import LandingPage from './LandingPage';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/some-page'>
          <SomePage />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/'>
          <LandingPage />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Problem**

When I run the react app only with `yarn start`, the routing works well. There's a link in the `LandingPage` component that navigates to `'/some-page'` successfully (ie; the page looks as it should).

However, when I run the app from Flask with `python3 main.py`, I don't know how to route the request. I've tried:

```py
@app.route("/some-page")
def some_page():
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")
```

But that just returns the same page for `'/checkout'` as `'/'`. Any idea what I need to do to route this request correctly?

**EDIT**

This may be a duplicate of:

- [How to render a react component on any other page other than index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50234042/how-to-render-a-react-component-on-any-other-page-other-than-index-html)

Will check back later.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the top answer here put a lot of this into perspective for me:

- [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

In my set up above the *client-side* has no memory of the user's history. So, when a request is sent back to the server (ie; a refresh), and the url is one the server cannot return information for, there is a 404.

Since I am just creating a prototype I just replaced the `<BrowserRouter></BrowserRouter>` with `<HashRouter></HashRouter>`. This was the easiest set up to get desired behavior.